# ZF disable optgroup lable in select

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

To show a list of categories, I use the 'select' in a form.
I insert the categories from the database.

When I look through the select list I get something like this:

```
0 
art
```

The optgroup has a label with a number value. I want to remove the label
from it so I have just in the list:

```
art
```

Without the 0 from the optgroup label.

Thanks in advice.

Nicky

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a parent element - you can't have that not to be visible and all children visible - doesn't work
2. You would compromise the use of the optgroup

Conclusion:
Just don't use optgroups if you don't want them...